If $\gamma_v$ is geodesic, then $\gamma_{sv}$ is geodesic
I'm trying to solve the following:

Let $p\in S$ ($S$ is a surface) and $v\in T_{p}S$ and a $\delta > 0$ s.t. $\gamma_{v}:\left(-\delta,\delta\right)\to S$ is a geodesic and
$\gamma_{v}\left(0\right)=p$
$\gamma_{v}^{\prime}\left(0\right)=v$.
Let $s\le 1$. Show that $\gamma_{sv}$ is defined on $\left(-\frac{\delta}{s},\frac{\delta}{s}\right)$ and is given by $\gamma_{sv}\left(t\right)=\gamma_{v}\left(st\right) $

I'm trying to approach it by claiming that since $|sv|\le |v|$,  $\gamma_{sv}$ is defined on $\left(-\delta,\delta\right)$, but since $\delta$ depend only on $|v|$, then $\gamma_{sv}$ is defined on $\left(-\frac{\delta}{s},\frac{\delta}{s}\right)$. I'm not sure that I'm getting it right, and have no idea how to approach the second part of the qeustion. Thanks!

You haven't said whether you're working in a surface (elementary DG), a Riemannian manifold, a Lorentzian spacetime, or what; but in any case at some stage it will be necessary to use the definition of a geodesic, preferably as a solution to an ODE.

@AndrewD.Hwang Sorry, I'm working on a surface (elementary DG). I'll think about your suggestion, thanks.

Hint; As Andrew said, use the geodesic equation $\nabla_{\gamma'}\gamma'=0$ if you know what $\nabla$ stands for.

@MoisheKohan I'm not sure what it means, unfortunately, but thanks, I will look it up.

I suggest you edit your question to clarify what definition of a geodesic you are using.

You're starting with a curve $\gamma$ and defining a brand new curve, call it $c$. Find a formula for $c(t)$ in terms of $\gamma$. To show that $c$ is a geodesic, it suffices to show that $c'(t)$ is normal to the surface.
